# What is the difference between Object and object in Python?

Tags: python, oop

When creating a class in python should it inherit from object or Object, or neither?
Is there any need to inherit from object at all?

```
class NewClass(object)
```

or

```
class NewClass(Object)
```

or

```
class NewClass()
```

Comment: Inheriting from `object` creates a ["new-style" class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python). You should always use this for new code in general. `Object` (with a capital O) doesn't exist in Python. And not inheriting from anything gives you an "old-style" class.

Comment: Very concise, but informative answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class inherits from `object` if it is a 'new style' object. It was a feature introduced in python2.2.

New style objects have a different object model to classic objects, and some things won't work properly with old style objects, for instance, `super()`, `@property`, and descriptors. See this article for a good description of what a new style class is:

[Python Documentation - Type and Class Changes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/sect-rellinks.html)

`Object`, on the other hand, seems to be a poorly named variable or object.

Comment: Very clear thanks. I guess I was confused because my IDE was highlighting Object (capital O) and it looked like a keyword to me.